# PHP: FPDF file is giving error in online server?

Tags: php, fpdf

My fpdf file which I have created is working well in localhost but when I uploaded in online server it is not displaying and giving that [error](http://usapaystubs.com/stub/stub.php).

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file (output started at /home/usapaystubs717/public_html/stub/stub.php:1)' in /home/usapaystubs717/public_html/stub/fpdf.php:271 Stack trace: #0 /home/usapaystubs717/public_html/stub/fpdf.php(1040): FPDF->Error('Some data has a...') #1 /home/usapaystubs717/public_html/stub/fpdf.php(987): FPDF->_checkoutput() #2 /home/usapaystubs717/public_html/stub/stub.php(213): FPDF->Output() #3 {main} thrown in /home/usapaystubs717/public_html/stub/fpdf.php on line 271

**Here is the code**

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
}
$pdf = new FPDF();

$pdf->AddPage();
/*$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');*/
 // 20mm from each edge

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);

/*$pdf->MultiCell(95,6,"Pakistan",'BB');*/
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"Welcome ",3,0,'L');

$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 15);
$pdf->SetXY(160 , 30);
$pdf->Write(10, "May 8, 2016");
$pdf->Line(18, 45, 210-20, 45);


$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 10);
$pdf->SetXY(10 , 54);
$pdf->Write(10, "PAY");

$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 11);
$pdf->SetXY(18.5 , 54);
$pdf->Write(10, "ONE THOUSAND TWO HUNDRED THIRTY");
/*$pdf->SetXY(110, 30);
$pdf->MultiCell(95,6,"Pakistan",'BB','R');*/
$pdf->SetXY(18 , 75);
$pdf->Cell(35,10,"Pay to the order of ",1,0,'C');

$pdf->SetXY(55, 79);
$pdf->MultiCell(95,6,"Zain Farooq",'BB','L');
/*$pdf->Line(20, 45, 210-20, 45);
$pdf->Line(50, 45, 210-50, 45);*/
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
$pdf->setFillColor(0,0,0);
$pdf->SetTextColor(255,255,255);
$pdf->Cell(80, 6, 'COMPANY INFORMATION', 1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',18);
$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
$pdf->setFillColor(230,230,230);
$pdf->Cell(80, 23, 'Earnings statement', 1 ,0,'C',1);


$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',8);
$pdf->SetXY(10 , 97);
$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
$pdf->MultiCell(80, 17, 'Extra statements', 'BL' ,'L');
$pdf->SetXY(10 , 103);
$pdf->MultiCell(90,11,"",'BL','R');
/*$pdf->Cell(80, 11, 'Extra statements', 1 ,0,'UL');*/

/*$pdf->Cell(50, 6, 'Itinerary', 1);
$pdf->Cell(19.75, 6, 'ETD', 1, 0, 'C');
$pdf->Cell(19.75, 6, 'ETA', 1, 0, 'C');
$pdf->Cell(19.75, 6, 'Block', 1, 0, 'C');
$pdf->Cell(19.75, 6, 'Waiting', 1, 0, 'C');*/
$pdf->Ln();



$pdf->Ln();

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',8);
$pdf->SetXY(10 , 114);
$pdf->setFillColor(0,0,0);
$pdf->SetTextColor(255,255,255);
$pdf->Cell(80, 6, 'Employee Information', 1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(40, 6, 'Social Security', 1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(40, 6, 'Employee ID', 1, 0, 'C',1);

$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
$pdf->SetXY(10 , 114);
$pdf->Cell(80, 18, '4323', 1);


$pdf->Ln();

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',8);
$pdf->SetXY(90 , 120);
$pdf->setFillColor(255,255,255);
$pdf->Cell(40, 4, 'XXX-XX-123', 1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(40, 4, '123456', 1, 0, 'C',1);

$pdf->Ln();

$pdf->Ln();

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',8);
$pdf->SetXY(90 , 124);
$pdf->setFillColor(0,0,0);
$pdf->SetTextColor(255,255,255);
$pdf->Cell(20, 4, 'Start Date', 1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(20, 4, 'End Date', 1, 0, 'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(40, 4, 'Check Date', 1, 0, 'C',1);

$pdf->Ln();


$pdf->Ln();

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',8);
$pdf->SetXY(90 , 128);
$pdf->setFillColor(255,255,255);
$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
$pdf->Cell(20, 4, 'Start Date', 1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(20, 4, 'End Date', 1, 0, 'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(40, 4, 'Check Date', 1, 0, 'C',1);

$pdf->Ln();




$pdf->Ln();

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',8);
$pdf->SetXY(10 , 132.3);
$pdf->setFillColor(0,0,0);
$pdf->SetTextColor(255,255,255);
$pdf->Cell(20, 6, 'Earnings', 1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(20,6, 'Rate', 1, 0, 'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(20,6, 'Hours', 1, 0, 'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(20, 6, 'Current', 1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(20, 6, 'Year to date', 1, 0, 'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(20, 6, 'Deductions', 1, 0, 'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(20, 6, 'Current', 1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(20, 6, 'Year to date', 1, 0, 'C',1);


$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->Ln();

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',8);
$pdf->SetXY(10 , 137.3);
$pdf->setFillColor(255,255,255);
$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
$pdf->Cell(20, 50, 'Earnings', 1,0,'T',1);
$pdf->Cell(20,50, 'Rate', 1, 0, 'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(20,50, 'Hours', 1, 0, 'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(20, 50, 'Current', 1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(20, 50, 'Year to date', 1, 0, 'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(20, 50, 'Deductions', 1, 0, 'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(20, 50, 'Current', 1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(20, 50, 'Year to date', 1, 0, 'C',1);


$pdf->Ln();

$pdf->Ln();

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',8);
$pdf->SetXY(10 , 187.3);
$pdf->setFillColor(230,230,230);
$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
$pdf->Cell(60, 6, 'Earnings', 1,0,'R',1);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',8);
$pdf->Cell(20, 6, '1600.00', 1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(20, 6, '14,400.00', 1, 0, 'C',1);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',8);
$pdf->Cell(20, 6, 'Deductions', 1, 0, 'C',1);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',8);
$pdf->Cell(20, 6, '370.00', 1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(20, 6, '3,300.00', 1, 0, 'C',1);


$pdf->Ln();

$pdf->Ln();

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',8);
$pdf->SetXY(10 , 193.3);
$pdf->setFillColor(255,255,255);
$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
$pdf->Cell(26.66667, 6, 'Check Number', 1,0,'R',1);

$pdf->Cell(26.66667, 6, '#6059', 1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(26.66667, 6, 'Net Pay', 1, 0, 'C',1);

$pdf->Cell(26.66667, 6, '$1,230', 1, 0, 'C',1);

$pdf->Cell(26.66667, 6, 'YTD NET PAY', 1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(26.66667, 6, '$11,070', 1, 0, 'C',1);


$pdf->Ln();

$pdf->Ln();

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',8);
$pdf->SetXY(10 , 199.5);
$pdf->setFillColor(0,0,0);

$pdf->Cell(160, 5, '', 1, 0, '',1);


$pdf->Ln();




/*Output('filename.pdf','D');*/
$pdf->Output();



?>
```

Comment: The error clearly says that you have output *something*, may be php or html code before `$fpdf->Output();`. Check that.

Comment: Thanx for response.. I don't think that that code has any output of php or html. I have also added the code

Comment: Since you're saying, *...working well in localhost but when I uploaded in online server it is not displaying*, may be `session.auto_start` value is the root cause of this, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18172502/5517143). You can also refer to [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475686/fpdf-error-some-data-has-already-been-output-cant-send-pdf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this

```
<?php
ini_set("session.auto_start", 0);
require('fpdf.php');
```

or

```
<?php
ob_start();
require('fpdf.php');
```

Answer (score 1):

as stated in another question [FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475686/fpdf-error-some-data-has-already-been-output-cant-send-pdf), you should check if you already sent some output. Output can be an "echo", or some markup or even some leading space before the php opening tag. From the link that you gave it seems there is an empty line before the error.

Comment: Hi, is it has any problem with comments?

Comment: I have removed all the spaces even between php lines. It is still not running in online server

Answer (score 0):

try re-encode the file to UTF-8 without BOM, this work for me